# Delete duplicates in Realm

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform

How can i remove duplicates from Realm database? I'am trying something like this, but it only remove duplicates from the "old" records in database.

```
    private void addRecord(){

    realm.beginTransaction();

    ResultFavorite resultFavorite = realm.createObject(ResultFavorite.class);
    resultFavorite.setImage(image);
    resultFavorite.setTitle(gameTitle.getText().toString());
    resultFavorite.setReleaseDate(gameReleaseDate.getText().toString());
    resultFavorite.setScore(Integer.parseInt(gameScore.getText().toString()));


    RealmResults<ResultFavorite> results = realm.where(ResultFavorite.class).equalTo("title",gameTitle.getText().toString()).findAll();

    results.deleteLastFromRealm();

    realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

This is my solution to avoid duplicates in Realm database.

```
   private void addRecord(){

    realm.beginTransaction();

    ResultFavorite object = realm.where(ResultFavorite.class)
            .equalTo("title", gameTitle.getText().toString())
            .findFirst();
    if(object == null){
        ResultFavorite resultFavorite = realm.createObject(ResultFavorite.class);
        resultFavorite.setImage(image);
        resultFavorite.setTitle(gameTitle.getText().toString());
        resultFavorite.setReleaseDate(gameReleaseDate.getText().toString());
        resultFavorite.setScore(Integer.parseInt(gameScore.getText().toString()));

    } else {

    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Comment: I see a problem with your code

Comment: what kind of problem?

Comment: the problem of remove duplicates from the "old" records in the database. Fix this bug will solve the issue

Comment: mhm... thanks for your very important advice:P